# Jquery validation - date rules to check if selected date is 5 days greater than current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a date picker control with id "dueDate", in my validation rules, i want users to only select dates greater than 5 days from current.

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control left" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" placeholder="Select Date.." />
```

I'm using jquery datepicker.

rules

```
rules: {

            dueDate: {
                required: true,
                date: true
                greaterThan: // need help here
            }
        }
```

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out when five days from now is just by modifying the `Date()` object:

```
var fiveDaysFromNow = new Date();
fiveDaysFromNow.setDate(fiveDaysFromNow.getDate() + 5);
```

Then just give `fiveDaysFromNow` to your script:

```
rules: {

        dueDate: {
            required: true,
            date: true,
            greaterThan: fiveDaysFromNow
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! kind of new to Jquery validation and the documentation is not so friendly.

Comment: TBH, i've never used it. :P I just scanned the documentation to see if it accepts a `Date` object (which it should, but always worth it to check...) and then used normal JS.